# How to update an access database table straight from GUI in Java using netbeans

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, database-connection, ms-access-2007

I have implemented a form using Netbeans where I managed to insert, update and delete, using text fields. Now, I am trying to do the same thing, but using a JTable. I can display the table, but I have not been able to update.  I then, started playing with my netbeans settings and even on my form using text fields, I can't update the data anymore. I can't find my mistakes, but the output says:

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]Error in row
```

I have been researching for the error message and still, I cant find a solution. 
I tried using the single quotes around where I am using the text fields to insert things into the database, but it also gave me an error.

I would be really gratful ii someone could send me a tutorial/code/link for update an access table in Java.

PS: my update code is inside an update button in the gui.

Answer (score 1):

Your problems have nothing to do with either NetBeans or Swing; it's a JDBC issue.

You'll get more help here if you post the code that does the updating.

If not, have a look at the JDBC tutorial:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html

Any time I receive an error I cut & paste it into Google.  I usually find out that I'm not the first person to experience the issue.  Here's what doing that with your error turned up:

http://www.programmersresource.com/forum/showthread.php?t=2704